# How to setup proxy in your network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, proxy, lan

I have cisco DPC2320 WiFi Modem. I want to setup a proxy in my whole network. So that any device which  connects to my network through WiFi or LAN would have a proxy.
Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want A http/https -proxy enforced on all traffic, you would have to port forward all traffic headed towards !localnets ports 80 and 443 to your proxy, in your router, while allowing your proxy to establish sessions outwards. Squid is most widely used as proxy software so I'd recommend starting there.

Please note that !localnets means every network that is not locally configured and usually requires a variable or local subnet with inverse-function to be specified in you firewall.

You could also use proxy auto configuration and denying traffic from hosts to the Internet but will require you to set up PAC.